# move enemy to the left

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm still struggling with as3. My enemy won't move from right to left. The other side is no problem. Does anybody no what i'm doing wrong? The trace goleft is work.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class mcEnemy extends MovieClip {

        public var sDirection:String;

        private var nSpeed:Number; 

        public function mcEnemy() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
        }

        private function onAdd (e:Event): void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
            init();
        }

        //radom enemy's worden gekozen
        private function init ():void
        {
            // 3 frames
            var nEnemies:Number = 3;
            // pick random number between 1 and number of enemies
            var nRandom:Number = randomNumber (1, nEnemies);
            // Setup our playhead of this enemy clip to a random number
            // Stop op frame 1,2 of 3
            this.gotoAndStop(nRandom);
            // Setup our enemys start position
            setupStartPosition();
        }

        private function setupStartPosition (): void
        {
            // pick a random speed for the enemy
            nSpeed = randomNumber (5,10); 
            // Pick random number for left or right, tussen 1 en 2, start position
            var nLeftOrRight:Number = randomNumber (1,2);
            // if our nLeftOrRight == 1 , enemy is on the left
            if (nLeftOrRight == 1)
            {
                // start enemy on the left side
                this.x =  - (this.width/2);
                sDirection = "R";
                //trace ("right");
            } else
            {
                // start enemy on the right side
                this.x = stage.stageWidth + (this.width/2);
                sDirection = "L";
                //trace("left");
            }
            // set a random hoogte for our enemy
            // set a 2 varibele for min and max hoogte
            var nMinAltitude: Number = stage.stageHeight/2;
            var nMaxAltitude: Number = 720 - (this.height/2);

            // Setup our enemies altitude to a random point between our min and max altitudes
            this.y = randomNumber (nMinAltitude, nMaxAltitude);

            // move our enemy
            startMoving ();
        }

        private function startMoving (): void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop)
        }

        private function enemyLoop (e:Event ): void
        {
            // test in what direction our enemy is moving
            // if our enemy is moving right
            if (sDirection == "R")
            {
                // move our enemy right
                this.x += nSpeed;
                //trace ("goright");
            } else
            {
                // move our enemy left
                this.x -= nSpeed;
                //trace ("goleft");
            }
        }

        // geeft random nummer tussen 0 en 1 en stuurt het terug
        function randomNumber (low:Number=0, high:Number=1) : Number
        {
            return Math.floor (Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
        }

            public function destroyEnemy (): void
        {
            // remove enemys from the stage
            if (parent) {
            parent.removeChild(this);   
            }
            // remove any eventlisteners from enemy
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enemyLoop);
        }

    }

}
```

I hope someone can help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see and think of, is that "var nLeftOrRight:Number = randomNumber (1,2);" creates a random number between 1 and 2, with decibels(1.2929291 for instance), and then you turn it into an int, which makes the possibility of 1 REALLY high, and the chance of 2 REALLY low..., if this is the case don't make it randomNumber(1,2), but randomNumber(1,3), then to catch the 'possible' 3 you need to make an if for when it's 3 and turn it into eighter 1 or 2...

I could be wrong about the random number generation thingy though so excuse me if i give wrong information

Answer (score 0):

What happens when it's supposed to move to the left? does it allways just move right or does it just sometimes go right and sometimes not move at all?

Comment: it's part of a game. Enemys are supposed to go left or right on the screen en you have to shoot them down. Because it is random i think the one who are supposed to go to the left aren't moving at all.